# What causes Ajax.BeginForm to go crazy when Bootstrap Modal Divs are accidentally kept within the parent Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

**Setup**

I had an MVC View containing a Partial View that had an Ajax.BeginForm. 
This was in turn triggering bootstrap modal pop ups for subsequent operations.
I enabled Unobtrusive validation and included Unobtrusive Ajax script references.
All my scripts were of the latest JQuery version.
Mine was an ASP.NET MVC5 application running on .NET 4.5 framework with razor views.

**Problem**

All hell broke loose when I ran this web application.
1)Bootstrap backdrop remained after modal was hidden.
2)Form was submitted twice
3)Submit button was rendering the Json result directly on the browser instead of sending it to onSuccess designated method.

Troubleshooting this from scratch, I realized that I had included the Modal dialog DIVs (the one which we refer in the data-target attribute) inside the Ajax.BeginForm of my partial view (thinking that those are anyways being triggered from within the partial view).

Keeping them out of the form resolved the issue.

Why can't the Modal Divs be kept within the Ajax.BeginForm? Is this caused due to the way the Bootstrap treats and invokes the Modals?

Comment: i am guessing here, but i had some issues with the modal before in 2.3. but i believe that the ajax submit is being fired before the modal hide event has a chance to fire which would leave the backdrop there. if the modal is not destroyed correctly the event handler for the submit button will still hang around which might cause the two submits.

Comment: @KevDevMan, I tend to agree with you on that. Is there a major difference then between keeping the DIVs within the form vs outside the form?